# Proving Series Convergence Using Taylor Polinomials

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I ask for some help with this question:

Suppose f(x) is continuous function on [0,1] and twice differentiated at x=0,
and $u_n=(-1)^n f\left(\frac 1n\right)$.

Prove : if $f(0)=0$ then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n$ converges.

I tried this way:

Lets represent $f(x)$ on $[0,1]$ as Maclaurin polynomial:

$$f\left(\frac 1n \right)=f(0)+\frac {f'(0)}n+ \frac {f''(0)} {2n^2} +R_n\left(\frac 1n \right)$$

Thus

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n f\left(\frac 1n \right)=
\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\left(\frac {f'(0)}n+ \frac {f''(0)} {2n^2} +R_n\left(\frac 1n \right) \right)$$.

If $f'(0)\neq 0$ then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac {f'(0)}n=f'(0)\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac 1n$ converges by Alternating Series Test.

If $f''(0)\neq 0$ then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac {f''(0)}{2n^2}=f''(0)\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac 1{2n^2}$ also converges by Alternating Series Test.

Therefore if $f'(0)\neq0$ or $f''(0) \neq0$
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\left(\frac {f'(0)}n+ \frac {f''(0)} {2n^2} \right)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n \frac {f'(0)}n+\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac {f''(0)}{2n^2}$ converges.

But what should I do with the remainder ?
There are no information provided to estimate the remainder.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The remainder poses no problem at all: it is *at least*
 $\;\mathcal O(n^{-3})\;$ and this thing converges without any problem.

In case the function isn't derivable thrice then develop McClaurin only up to the first derivative (linear approximation) and leave the second derivative for the remainder. As this second derivative's order is $\;\frac1{n^2}\;$ we're cool.

Comment: I am not familiar with the O-language. Could you explain,please, yours statement without using this ? Thank you.

Comment: This means the remainder is of the form $$\frac{a_1}{n^3}+\frac{a_2}{n^4}+\ldots$$ In fact, you can even use the Cauchy or the Lagrange form for the remainder and get an even easier expression.

Comment: I does not know if the third derivative of exists on [0,1], therefore I could not use the Cauchy or the Lagrange form for the remainder to estimate it value.

Comment: You are right. Then I have an idea: develop the McClaurin series **only** up to the first derivative $\;f'(0)\;$, argue as before and leave the second derivative to work with the remainder. Again we've no problem because this time the remainder is of order $\;1/n^2\;$ and this converges...Check this.